# What is the difference of idivl and divl?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have these expressions:

```
cltd
idivl   (%ecx)
```

when dividing by an `int`,  and:

```
movl    $0, %edx
divl    (%ecx)
```

when dividing an `unsigned long`

[cltd](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-49/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`idiv`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/idiv.htm) performs signed division, [`div`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/div.htm) performs unsigned division.