# Why using 'divl' when doing int / unsigned int division

Tags: c++, c, x86, unsigned-integer

I tested this code in X86.

```
void func()
{
  int a, b;
  unsigned int c, d;
  int ret;

  ret = a / b;  // This line use idivl, expected
  ret = c / d;  // this line use idivl, expected
  ret = a / c;  // this line use divl..., surprised 
  ret = c / a;  // this line use divl..., supriised
  ret = a * c;  // this line use imull, expected
}
```

I paste the assembly code here:

```
func:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $36, %esp
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    sarl    $31, %edx
    idivl   -8(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    $0, %edx
    divl    -16(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    movl    $0, %edx
    divl    -12(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -36(%ebp)
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    $0, %edx
    divl    -36(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    imull   -12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)
    leave
    ret
```

Could you please tell me, why the division between int and unsigned int using divl , instead of idivl ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489098/what-is-the-difference-of-idivl-and-divl

Comment: @Orwell: that question explains what those instructions do, not why the compiler picked one over the other. A proper answer in this case would be a citation from the C/C++ standard detailing type conversion/promotion during mathematical operations (dividing signed and unsigned integers).

Comment: I see 3 `divl`s and only one `idivl` in your pasted assembly. Your comments in the C suggest it should be 2 and 2...

Comment: The compiler uses unsigned division when unsigned values are involved. What's the surprise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the types of `a` and `c` have the same conversion rank, but `a` is signed and `c` is unsigned, `a` is converted to `unsigned int` before the division, in both `a / c` and `c / a`.

The compiler thus emits the unsigned division instruction `div` for these cases (as well as `c / d`, where both operands are unsigned).

The multiplication `a * c` is also an unsigned multiplication.  In this case the compiler can get away with using the signed multiplication instruction `imull`, because the truncated result is identical regardless of whether `mull` or `imull` is used - only the flags are different, and the generated code doesn't test those.

Comment: It's not "promoted", it's "converted". Conversion is usually more surprising than promotion (e.g. -1 is converted to 4294967295, which cannot happen with promotion)

Comment: I write code to check, it is the case, the int is converted to unsigned int before doing division... printf("%d\n", ((unsigned int)10)/-1); will output ZERO, which seems very strange! caf you are right, thanks a lot !

Comment: BTW, this kind of conversion will definitely cause some unexpected behavior, may I know why C choose to do the conversion this way ? Why not converted both to signed, we have widen bits in register anyway ..