# Curious arithmetic error- 255x256x256x256=18446744073692774400

Tags: c++, multiplication, uint64

I encountered a strange thing when I was programming under c++.  It's about a simple multiplication.

Code:

```
unsigned __int64 a1 = 255*256*256*256;
unsigned __int64 a2= 255 << 24; // same as the above

cerr()<<"a1 is:"<<a1;
cerr()<<"a2 is:"<<a2;
```

interestingly the result is:

```
a1 is: 18446744073692774400 
a2 is: 18446744073692774400
```

whereas it should be:(using calculator confirms)

```
4278190080
```

Can anybody tell me how could it be possible?

Comment: It's called undefined behaviour

Comment: Serious passions on post rating :) From -3 to 2 and back in 5 seconds.

Comment: Don't see why this received 8 upvotes...

Comment: @H2CO3: Because it's a "non-obvious language quirk that is super interesting" and not because the question is well formulated or researched...

Comment: @H2CO3: Yeah, let's nobody code anything ever in a language we don't 110% understand.  You do realize, don't you, that if we took that mindset we'd never learn anything new?

Comment: An annoying thing about C++ compilers is that using them without turning warnings on will let you make tons of mistakes you shouldn't have to. When I compile this code in GCC with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, the compiler tells me quite clearly: "warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]". Microsoft Visual Studio also diagnoses this problem: "warning C4307: '*' : integral constant overflow". I hope this serves as a lesson to compile with warnings on in the future.

Comment: Kind of the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487923/why-overflow-happens-on-calculation-depending-on-the-data-type-when-the-type-whe#comment16802182_12487923

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes For the multiplication, my g++ (4.5.1, yeah, old) warns with default warning level.

Comment: Another way to avoid overflow might be using literal suffixes.  Depending on your compiler, `255ULL * 256 * 256 * 256` could work.

Comment: @aschepler Not only "could", _must_, per the standard.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Is `unsigned long long` guaranteed to have at least 64 bits?  (Admittedly, it would be silly for a compiler to support a `__int64` type and not make it an alias for `long long`.)

Comment: @DanielFischer: hence "depending on your compiler", since everyone's still busy implementing the current standard. `unsigned long long` isn't in C++03, so to use it you need either a compiler-specific extension to C++03 or (for the time being) a compiler-specific partial implementation of C++11. In practice *everybody* has `long long`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Ah, yes, I forgot how lagging C++ was in that respect.

Comment: @aschepler: the minimum conforming value of `ULLONG_MAX` is `18446744073709551615`, which is the standard's way of saying "at least 64 bits".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
 255*256*256*256
```

all operands are `int` you are overflowing `int`. The overflow of a signed integer is undefined behavior in C and C++.

**EDIT:**

note that the expression `255 << 24` in your second declaration also invokes undefined behavior if your `int` type is `32-bit`. `255 x (2^24)` is `4278190080` which cannot be represented in a `32-bit` `int` (the maximum value is usually `2147483647` on a `32-bit` `int` in two's complement representation).

C and C++ both say for `E1 << E2` that if `E1` is of a signed type and positive and that `E1 x (2^E2)` cannot be represented in the type of `E1`, the program invokes undefined behavior. Here `^` is the mathematical *power* operator.

Comment: Thanks,It worked with unsigned __int64 a1 = 255*256*256;
a1=a1*256;

Comment: just my curiosity, but is int64 should have 64 bits? and 255*256*256*256 = ff 00 00 00 and  is 32bit number

Comment: @user902383: Those 255s and 256s are ints.  So C++ does all the intermediate steps with ints (which are more than likely 32 bits).  Numerically, it winds up with 0xFF000000.  Convert that to signed 64-bit, and you get 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000 (sign extension).  This is just one way it could happen, but it's by far the most common one.

Comment: Isn't this different than in C, where the type of a literal is determined by its size?

Comment: @rubenvb: AFAIK, even in C, whole-number literals are ints unless you specifically tell them to be otherwise (via a cast or suffix).  They just get converted to the appropriate size as needed, which in this case is *after* all the math is done.

Comment: @cHao No, since C99, the type is determined by size, the first in a list (`int`, `long int`, `long long int` for decimal constants without suffix, plus the corresponding `unsigned` types for octal or hexadecimal constants; minus the types excluded by a suffix) the constant fits in is the type.

Comment: Anyway, `256` is guaranteed to have type `int` since it fits in an `int`. Multiplying it by something else doesn't change that, the literals are all small.

Comment: One could argue the whole multiplication is a constant literal, but I'm sure I'm wrong. "If only C(++) was designed to be nice" is very applicable here.

Comment: @rubenvb: yeah, you couldn't argue that based on the standard, because the definition of a literal in the standard is a simple matter of syntax, and `256*255` isn't it :-)

Comment: @rubenvb It's a "constant expression", and overflow in that makes the program ill-formed.

Answer (score 17):

Your literals are `int`. This means that all the operations are actually performed on `int`, and promptly overflow. This overflowed value, when converted to an unsigned 64bit int, is the value you observe.

Comment: The fundamental mistake of the OP is far wider spread than this example: It's the misguided assumption that the type of the *left-hand side* somehow exudes magic powers on the right hand side and makes it clairvoyantly change behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB Come on. People simply don't expect overflow since the end of the 8 bit era, and it's not unreasonable to expect literals (or expressions of only literals) to be typed automatically.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I think it would be fairly insane if the *type* of an expression depended on the *values* of its constituents... how would you even specify that? What's the type of `256 * n`?

Comment: @KerrekSB hence, "only literals." But it's common (or good practice, IMHO) to specify a large constant number as a product of several smaller ones. This does happen in real life.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Doesn't Pyhton do that? I think I saw something about it upgrading the type upon overflow.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I know that you meant only literals, but again, how would you specify that? It seems to me that you'd get into a mess.

Comment: @chris: yes, Python does that, by dynamically allocating enough memory for the value. That's "too heavyweight" for C.

Comment: @Kerrek: I don't think it would be difficult to define "expressions only involving literals", no more difficult than defining "integer constant expression" in C++. But even if the standard did do that, someone would want another special case where the type is different, and the rules would get more complicated again. Btw, the lhs does exude magical powers on the rhs in one case, which is assigning a function or member function pointer from an overloaded name. Dig deep enough and even misguided assumptions can become guided in special cases ;-)

Answer (score 16):

It is perhaps worth explaining what happened to produce the number 18446744073692774400.  Technically speaking, the expressions you wrote trigger "undefined behavior" and so the compiler could have produced *anything* as the result; however, assuming `int` is a 32-bit type, which it almost always is nowadays, you'll get the same "wrong" answer if you write

```
uint64_t x = (int) (255u*256u*256u*256u);
```

and that expression does *not* trigger undefined behavior. (The conversion from `unsigned int` to `int` involves *implementation-defined* behavior, but as nobody has produced a ones-complement or sign-and-magnitude CPU in many years, all implementations you are likely to encounter define it exactly the same way.)  I have written the cast in C style because everything I'm saying here applies equally to C and C++.

First off, let's look at the multiplication.  I'm writing the right hand side in hex because it's easier to see what's going on that way.

```
255u * 256u               = 0x0000FF00u
255u * 256u * 256u        = 0x00FF0000u
255u * 256u * 256u * 256u = 0xFF000000u (= 4278190080)
```

That last result, `0xFF000000u`, has the highest bit of a 32-bit number set.  Casting that value to a *signed* 32-bit type therefore causes it to become negative as-if 2<sup>32</sup> had been subtracted from it (that's the implementation-defined operation I mentioned above).

```
(int) (255u*256u*256u*256u) = 0xFF000000 = -16777216
```

I write the hexadecimal number there, sans `u` suffix, to emphasize that the *bit pattern* of the value does not change when you convert it to a signed type; it is only reinterpreted.

Now, when you assign -16777216 to a `uint64_t` variable, it is back-converted to unsigned as-if by adding 2<sup>64</sup>.  (Unlike the unsigned-to-signed conversion, this semantic is prescribed by the standard.)  This *does* change the bit pattern, setting all of the high 32 bits of the number to 1 instead of 0 as you had expected:

```
(uint64_t) (int) (255u*256u*256u*256u) = 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000u
```

And if you write `0xFFFFFFFFFF000000` in decimal, you get 18446744073692774400.

As a closing piece of advice, whenever you get an "impossible" integer from C or C++, try printing it out in hexadecimal; it's much easier to see oddities of twos-complement fixed-width arithmetic that way.

Comment: The conversion to unsigned types is prescribed by the standard (4.7. in C++03, probably somewhere similar in C++11; 6.3.1.3 in C99 and C11) to be reduction modulo `2^WIDTH`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple -- overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here Overflow occurred on int and when you are assigning it to unsigned int64 its converted in to 18446744073692774400 instead of 4278190080